# How to fix App not installed error on android 10?

Tags: android, apk

I created my app, generated a signed apk and tried to install it. I got an error App not installed. I rebooted the device, resigned apk, tried again. But nothing worked. On the emulator everything is ok. How can I fix the problem? I try to install apk to android 10. The minimum SDK is 21. Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I don't know what else may influence and cause this error. Please, help me

Comment: is the application installed on your device using the usb while debugging?

Comment: No, I generated signed apk, uploaded it to google drive from pc and downloaded it using phone

Comment: @MaxSiomin hello, Max! Sorry for off-topic, but I have a question about your recently deleted question `Huawei ads kit failed to load with error code 2`. Could you please tell me, did you find an answer? You can write me to email dezarion1@gmail.com. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Scenario one
  The application where you want to install your app from whether it was `Google Drive` or `File Manager` doesn't have the permission to `Install apps from unknown sources`
  So go to the >> App info and set this permission enabled.
- Scenario Two
  Installing an app from `Google Drive` issue happened with a client of mine, and we were uploading the app to `MediaFire` instead.
  I think in that case the application would be downloaded and installed from the browser `Chrome` and by turn it should have the same permission `Install apps from unknow sources` enabled.

Don't forget If an old version of the app was installed on your device make sure to un-install it manually